# String interpolation inside ngFor (click)="..."

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, string-interpolation

Looping through array inside ngFor like so:

```
<div *ngFor="account of accounts">
    <button (click)="function1(); account.message='How do I interpolate {{account.something}} here'"
</div>
```

I receive error `Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected`
If I just do `account.something` without interpolation since it is between the single quotes it will print as literal `How do I interpolate account.something`

Comment: I usually find it best to have as little logic and code in a binding as possible. I'd suggest putting a separate handler in your module and have the click handler just read `(click)="function2(account)"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use string concatenation like:

```
(click)="account.message='How do I interpolate ' + account.something + ' here'"
```

Comment: Ok it worked...thought I had tried that already and it didn't lol. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You already going to write javascript inside the double quotes, so you no need to write interpolation syntax.

```
(click)="All javascript code can be written here without interpolation syntax"
```